# eloquent how to add all values of an array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, frameworks

for example i have the following codes in my controller:

```
foreach($-request->input('text') as $var){
$sum[] = $var;
}

$last = sizeof($request->input('text'));
$i = 0; 
while($i < $last)
{
 //insert code here
 $i++;
}
```

`$request->input('text')` has the following values:

```
['1,2,3,4,5']
```

how do you add the values in the variable `$var[]` in eloquent? i tried the `sum` but it didn't work. someone also said ill use `+=` sign on my increment

Comment: `$-request->input('text')` typo error?

Answer (score 2):

1. `explode` to convert comma-separated numbers into an array.
2. `intval` on all array elements using `array_map` to cast them into integer.
3. `array_sum` to add them all.

Try this.

```php
$array = $request->input('text'); // ['1, 2, 3, 4, 5'];

$string_numbers = explode(', ', $array[0]); // ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

$numbers = array_map('intval', $string_numbers); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

echo array_sum($numbers); // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $num = ['1,2,3,4,5'];   // when $n = $request->input('text');
    $numbers = explode(',', $num[0]);
    $sum = array_sum($numbers);
    dd($sum);
```

I think this will be helpful to you